# Extract Info from ListView

Tags: c#, wpf

i have a list view filled with data coming from a device (CanCase XL) linked to my PC, way i fill the list view is :

```
_Lvf.Add(new listViewFrames()
{
    dlc = DLC,
    Byte1 = Byte1,
    Byte2 = Byte2,
    Byte3 = Byte3,
    Byte4 = Byte4,
    Byte5 = Byte5,
    Byte6 = Byte6,
    Byte7 = Byte7,
    Byte8 = Byte8,
});
```

after this operation i want to extract all this data filled in mylistview to a "table" in this way i can start analysing data one by one,
I have tried with

```
((DataRowView)(myListView.SelectedItem)).Row.ItemArray[0]
```

but it return only the first row.
I want to extract all in a single shot, is there a way?

Comment: Why not put it in a table first and then bind it to the listview?

Comment: @Koen i have used backgroundworker to extract those data from the device i think its not a good idea to put those data in table first !!!

Comment: @user2933082 what does a backgroundworker have to do with putting this in a data table or not?

Comment: @decPL in fact ... nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments it's easier to add the data to a datatable first and then bind it to the listview.

Quick and dirty sample:

C#:

```
    private DataTable dataTable;

    private void BackgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataTable = new DataTable();

        // Add your data here
        this.dataTable.Columns.Add("Col1");
        this.dataTable.Rows.Add("1");
        this.dataTable.Rows.Add("2");
        this.dataTable.Rows.Add("3");
        this.dataTable.Rows.Add("4");
        this.dataTable.Rows.Add("5");
    }

    void BackgroundWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.ListView1.DataContext = this.dataTable.DefaultView;
    }
```

XAML:

```
    <ListView Name="ListView1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col1}" Header="Col1" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Just on the top of my mind and using Notepad++, so there could be a typo in it ;-)